# How to make .exe file in borland C++ builder 6

Tags: c++, installation, c++builder, c++builder-6

I need help to make my application run on another computer with it's own installer. What files do I have to include to it and how to make it?

Comment: Are you really going to use a compiler from 2002?

Comment: What is it you're asking. How to compile your sources into an executable? Or how to create an installer for your binaries?

Comment: If it's an installer, it's not necessarily important what compiler you used.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is to make your .exe file self-contained by statically linking all the runtime libraries:

1. Set the **Link with Dynamic RTL** option to false.
2. Set the **Link with runtime packages** option to false.

Otherwise you need to redistribute the runtime dependencies. The [documentation contains a section on deployment](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Deploying_Applications_Overview), although you'll need to read your local documentation since you are using a very old version of the product. *Update*: it's chapter 17 in this [document](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/cbuilder6/EN/CB6_DevelopersGuide_EN.pdf).

As for how to make an installer, there are a gazillion tools that do that. Choose one and get it to do the hard work.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page) if you want to create an installer.